# Python replace function, Can it be done more beautiful?

Tags: python, replace

can this be done in less lines

```
text = "DKK 5.000,33"
text2 = text.replace('DKK ', '')

text3 = text2.replace('.', '')
text4 = text3.replace(',','.')
print(float(text4))
```

It outputs what i want, it just looks so bad, and im hoping it can be done more beautiful so i dont have to make 4 new variables to change a text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call replace on text as many times as you want.

```
text = "DKK 5.000,33"
text2 = text.replace('DKK ', '').replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
print(float(text2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/vgiknr/1) with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) checking for all 3 cases and use a group for the comma.

Replace `DKK`  or `.` with an empty string, and if group 1 is present replace a comma with a `.`

```
text = "DKK 5.000,33"
text = re.sub(r"DKK |\.|(,)", lambda m: "." if m.group(1) else "", text)
print(float(text))
```

Output

```
5000.33
```